# Labels overlapping in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am using QGIS 3.22.

I have a shapefile with administrative areas in Germany that I filtered (query builder) to get only one name of adm areas I am interested in being capable of actually labelling it.
My issue is that the labels are overlapping and I did not manage to move it differently despite trying several options in the rendering tab under the label section.

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works